# python installation problem (app Dash & WSGI server)

Tags: python, installation

I have installed dash with the pip command : https://github.com/plotly/dash-cytoscape, but when I try to use it
[image]

I have run the example which is given.

I don't really understand the problem, I think I should just replace something, but I don't know what.
I have found this :https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/uwsgi/?highlight=wsgi, but I don't want to do error or something irreparable, so I prefer ask if someone have the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a "problem" actually. The message means that you launched a development server. A development server often means that it may not be fully optimized, and may not be secure enough to run in a production environment. If you want to deploy your app for public use, you'd better use a production WSGI server. But if you just want to play with it or use it during development, it's totally fine.

Comment: Ok, so I can use use it ? So, i see the results : http://127.0.0.1:8050/ Yes it's good thanks, I will take dash in hand first, and may be when i have a programm I will see how use a production WSGI server. Thanks.

Comment: @JulesMassart The message says it's running on `http://127.0.0.1:8050`, so open a network browser and input `http://127.0.0.1:8050` in url and you will see the results.

Comment: Yes, i see, with python i use to programing with jupyter, but the programm make a system error with jupyter, so I will use the line command and no problem with it the page appeared.